# python dict set min_size

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, python-2.7, hashtable

I'm parsing hundreds of millions of JSON records and storing the relevant components from each in a `dict`. The problem is that because of the number of records I'm processing, python is being forced to increase the size of the `dict`'s underlying hash table several times. This results in a LOT of data having to be rehashed. The sheer amount of rehashing itself seems to cost a lot of time. Therefore, I wonder if there's a way to set a minimum size on the `dict`'s underlying hash table so that the number of resizing operations is minimized.

I have read [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictnotes.txt?view=markup) on optimizing python's `dict`, from an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279358/pythons-underlying-hash-data-structure-for-dictionaries), but cannot find how to change the initial size of a `dict`'s hash table. If anyone can help me out with this, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
a = dict.fromkeys(range(n))
```

it will force the dictionary size to accomodate n items. It is quite quick after that, but it takes 3s to do so.

Comment: Sure, that gets me the right size. But it doesn't get me the right keys. I'd have to delete all the `n` many keys and repopulate with the correct ones, as I process each JSON record. Would that not be slow?

Comment: It should help with speed. Write a small test that does so. It'll create a dict of a known size with all values defaulting to either None or a value of your choice

Comment: Isn't there a neater solution than the artificial blowing the data structure with junk values? :(